# GWT CellTable Input Validation

Tags: java, validation, gwt, gwt-validation

I would like to implement something similar to the Cell Validation showcase example, which can be found here

http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellValidation

After looking through the code and trying to implement it, there seems to be a class/variable deffinition missing for template. which shows up in the code in 2 places

```
public ValidatableInputCell(String errorMessage) {
  super("change");
  if (template == null) {
    template = GWT.create(Template.class);
  }
  this.errorMessage = SimpleHtmlSanitizer.sanitizeHtml(errorMessage);
}

SafeStyles safeColor = SafeStylesUtils.fromTrustedString("color: " + color + ";");
sb.append(template.input(pendingValue != null ? pendingValue : value, safeColor));

if (invalid) {
  sb.appendHtmlConstant(" <span style='color:red;'>");
  sb.append(errorMessage);
  sb.appendHtmlConstant("</span>");
}
```

After searching the web i found a few examples of what the template variable definition should be and came up with

```
interface Template extends SafeHtmlTemplates {
  @Template("<input type=\"text\" value=\"{0}\" tabindex=\"-1\" size=\"{1}\"></input>")
  SafeHtml input(String value, SafeHtml safeStyles);
}
private Template template;
```

with the above code added in there are no compiler warning howver when the code is executed i get this error

> SafeStyles used in a non-CSS attribute context. Did you mean to use java.lang.String or SafeHtml instead?

Any ideas of how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The template definition you are looking for, misses the `@ShowcaseSource` annotation, hence you do not see it in the source tab of the validation sample.

Anyway, [here](https://gwt.googlesource.com/gwt/+/master/samples/showcase/src/com/google/gwt/sample/showcase/client/content/cell/CwCellValidation.java) is the original code. And the template is:

```
interface Template extends SafeHtmlTemplates {
  @Template("<input type=\"text\" value=\"{0}\" style=\"{1}\" tabindex=\"-1\"/>")
  SafeHtml input(String value, SafeStyles color);
}
```

The error you see is because you are using a `SafeStyle` element (referenced by `{1}`) as a value of the `size` attribute (instead of `style`).